# gnuplot: The format of the values on the axis with a constant power

Tags: format, gnuplot, axis

There are values on the y scale

> 0 0.02 0.04 0.06 0.08 0.1 0.12 0.14 0.16 0.18 0.2 ...

How to set the format
set format x ""

so that the data can be output in the form

```
0 
2 * 10^-2 
4 * 10^-2 
6 * 10^-2 
8 * 10^-2 
10 * 10^-2 
12 * 10^-2 
14 * 10^-2 
16 * 10^-2 
18 * 10^-2
20 * 10^-2
```

i.e. the initial base is selected automatically and the power does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear. Here is a guess at what you want.

when you plot the data, multiply it by 10**2. Then in the label, show that the data is *10^-2.

Example: if that line of data is 1 item per line, you would have:

```
plot 'dataFile.txt' using 1
```

Instead, try:

```
set ylabel 'DataName *10_{-2}'
plot 'dataFile.txt using ($1*10**2)
```

The above `set ylabel` assumes you have enhanced formatting turned on.

This is a rudimentary example. We can do better if you show us an actual piece of the data file and you include your `plot` statement so we can see what you are actually trying to do.